# Can I use Windows 10 without being online?

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to buy, install and use Windows 10 without ever being online again after the software has been checked for authenticity by Microsoft (as is done now for Windows 7)?

Comment: Of course, you won't get the Microsoft advertising and other products pushed to your PC. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- yes as with any Windows , it works offline (except for those Apps that need the Web)
- You can even update offline and more
  http://www.portableupdate.com/

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Yes, you can.

There is even an off-line authentication for your license key, so potentially you may never even 'need' to get on-line, however once you do establish a connection to the internet, whether it is via Wi-Fi or ethernet, Windows 10 will attempt to authenticate and perhaps update as well!